# Rexster OrientDB configuration

Tags: orientdb, tinkerpop, bulbs, rexster

i'm trying to setup Rexster (version 2.5) to work with OrientDB (1.7 rc2). The problem is that i don't know what should i put in the `<graph-type>` field in the graph configuration. Most recent Rexster documentation (https://github.com/tinkerpop/rexster/wiki/Specific-Graph-Configurations) states that OrientDB support was removed from the package, and therefore one has to copy orientdb-client and orientdb-enterprise jars from OrientDB distribution.

So that's what i did. Then i've setup the `<graph>` section as follows:

```
<graph>                                                                                                        
  <graph-enabled>true</graph-enabled>                                                                        
  <graph-name>test</graph-name>                                                                            
  <graph-type>com.tinkerpop.blueprints.impls.orient.OrientGraphRexsterConfiguration</graph-type>                             
  <graph-location>local:orientdb/databases/test</graph-location>                        
  <extensions>                                                                                               
    <allows>                                                                                               
      <allow>tp:gremlin</allow>                                                                          
    </allows>
  </extensions>                                                                                              
</graph>
```

I get `java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.tinkerpop.blueprints.impls.orient.OrientGraphRexsterConfiguration` upon Rexster startup.

I've also tried setting up Rexster 2.1, which works just fine when using `orientgraph` for `<graph-type>` (as per https://code.google.com/p/orient/wiki/Rexster). This approach fails for 2.5. I feel that i must be missing something obvious. Can someone please point to the solution?

Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

Looks like I didn't get the documentation quite right.  The `<graph-type>` should be:

```
com.tinkerpop.rexster.OrientGraphConfiguration
```

You can see the class here:

https://github.com/orientechnologies/orientdb/blob/develop/graphdb/src/main/java/com/tinkerpop/rexster/OrientGraphConfiguration.java

I've corrected the documentation.  As the class is still in the `develop` branch I'm not sure that it has been released yet.  I know Luca keeps track of what's going on here in StackOverflow, so perhaps he can offer additional comment on when that will be released.  If not you may want to write something to the OrientDB mailing list.